# library data modeling

Tags: database-design

[image]

I'm going to implement a library system as a web application. And I decided to use this library schema. But there are some problems which I don't understand.

1. The Books entity, is it possible to use isbn as a primary key?
2. Is there a possible relationship between the Books entity and the Libraries entity? Is it a correct many-to-many relationship? I think that any book must be in only one library. So it is considered that one-to-many is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Your model completely ignores the fact that books come in **multiple copies**.

Each *copy* of a book can only be in one place at one time, but each place could have multiple copies of any given book.

Since each copy of a book will have exactly the same ISBN, the answer to your first question is: "No, ISBN is not a sufficient primary key for `Books`."

What you need to account for is a `Title` entity.  This is going to be a combination of what you're thinking about for your `Books` entity.  A `Title` is an abstract object.  It will have a title, authors, publication date, and so forth.  You might even want to consider making a distinction between `Title` and `Edition`, since a book can be republished many times with variations each time.

Whether or not you want to distinguish between editions of a title, you must at least distinguish between `Title` and `Books`.  The answer to your second question is that each physical book will be in one place (either at a `Library` or on loan to a `Member` - or in transit between branches, or lost, etc. - depending on how sophisticated you want your model to be).

On the other hand, `Title`s, (or `Edition`s) will be many-to-many with locations.

Comment: How would you label individual (electronic) copies of a book? Add that to your answer and I would probably upvote it.

Comment: @TomAu Naming is one of the hardest parts of data modelling.  I would be inclined to use the term `Book` for the physical volumes.  As I noted in my answer I would call the abstract _collection_ of all printed copies containing the same content `Title`.  If someone thought `Book` was too ambiguous, I think libraries often use the term `Copy`.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. Suppose there are 1000 copies of a book in (electronic) circulation. How would you number them 1 to 1000?

Comment: @TomAu I think I would number them with a meaningless unique number encoded in a barcode sticker glued inside the cover of the book.  I don't think each copy needs to have an "external" (i.e. human-friendly) identifier.  This isn't necessary since people generally don't care about which copy of a book they have.  The copy ID is relevant to the system so it should be assigned in a way that is convenient to manage.  Pre-printed unique ID barcode stickers are convenient for the librarian who is cataloging the book.  You can glue in the sticker, scan it, and then associate it with the title.